# Socket.EndReceive(...) does not properly return

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am trying to use Socket.BeginReceive(...) and Socket.EndReceive(...) as my UDP Packet Receiver client.  It receives and processes packets as expected, however, when I wish to cancel and shutdown the socket, my implemented Close() function exits on Socket.EndReceive(...).  I assume an exception was thrown on the thread but I cannot figure out how to catch the exception to see what the problem is.  I have used Socket.EndReceive(...) before with the SocketError returning as Success.  Here is a bit of code that shows how I'm using the socket.

**Updated Code**

```
void _startReceiving()
{
    _buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(EthernetShare.Message))];
    _receiveResult = _udpSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, messageProcessor, null);
}

private void messageProcessor(IAsyncResult result)
{
    int packetSize = _udpSocket.EndReceive(result);
    if (packetSize == _buffer.Length)
    {
        byte[] packet = _buffer;
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = result;
        _startReceiving();
        OnMessageReceieved(_buffer.ToStruct<DataStreamingMessage>());
    }
}
public void Stop()
{

    _continue = false;
    SocketError error;
    try
    {
        int tmp = _udpSocket.EndReceive(_receiveResult, out error);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
    _udpSocket.Close();
}
```

**Old Code**

```
private Socket _udpSocket;
private byte[] _buffer;
private IAsyncResult _receiveResult;
void _startReceiving()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(EthernetShare.Message))];
    _receiveResult = _udpSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, messageProcessor, null);
    //_receiveResult = _udpSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, messageProcessor, _continue);
}

private void messageProcessor(IAsyncResult result)
{

    //if ((bool)result.AsyncState && result.IsCompleted)
    if (result.IsCompleted)
    {
        _buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (EthernetShare.Message))];
        //_receiveResult = _udpSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, messageProcessor, _continue);
        _receiveResult = _udpSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, messageProcessor, null);
    }
}


public void Stop()
{

    _continue = false;
    SocketError error;
    try
    {
        int tmp = _udpSocket.EndReceive(_receiveResult, out error);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
    _udpSocket.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of APM (Asynchronous Programming Model) is wrong. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx

Each call to BeginXXX should be matched with an EndXXX.

In pseudo code, it might look something like this:

```
private bool isClosed;
private Socket socket;

void BeginReceiveNextPacket(){
    socket.BeginReceive(..., EndReceiveNextPacket);
}

void EndReceiveNextPacket(IAsyncResult result){
    try{
        // By making a call to EndReceive, we allow the socket to wrap up, close internal handles and raise any exceptions if they exist.
        socket.EndReceive(result); 

        // Now make a new call to BeginReceive after we invoked the actual call to EndReceive.
        BeginReceiveNextPacket();
    }
    catch(SocketClosedException) {
        if (closed){
            // We forcefully closed this socket. Therefore, this exception was expected and we can ignore it.
        }
        else{
            throw; // Catch an unexpected exception.
        }
    }
}

void Stop(){
    isClosed = true;
    socekt.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, although I still have the issue when pairing every Begin with an End.  I posted an update to show my new update.

Comment: You cant have multiple calls to EndReceive. In your close method you make a call to EndReceive as well as in the callback. This conflicts. If you want  to wait in your close method for the current request to complete, then you can wait using the WaitHandle found in  _recieveResult

Comment: Indeed I see what you mean. I removed the EndReceive in the Stop function. Here is the problem, the client always assumes more data will be comming as such when I close the socket, the messageProcessor executes and when trying to execute EndReceive an ObjectDisposedException is thrown.  For some reason this doesn't seem like a proper shutdown.

Comment: When you close the socket, the pending receive will likely end prematurely. What you need to do is in the close function set a flag that indicates that you've closed the socket. Next in your receive callback only do the work (including endreceive) whenever the flag is not set.